# Starcrawlers: How can I exit a mission partway through?

Tags: starcrawlers

In [Starcrawlers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCrawlers), how can I exit a mission I am currently running?

I started a mission and am most of the way through, but won't be able to beat it. All but one of my characters have died. How can I exit the mission and go back to town to heal?

I searched through all of the menu options, but don't see any buttons or decisions for this. I am not able to call a ship to pick me up. There are no locations on the map to return. How do I get back?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: If it's a Story Mission, you can't.** You will have to go back to the last save from when you were in town, and start over from there. Save early, and save often.

Missions in Starcrawlers are divided into two types: "Story Missions" and regular missions. In regular missions you can exit any time, at fairly frequent locations. You will see a green 'exit door' line on the map. If you look aound that spot, there should be an object you can interact with called "Exit Hatch". You can use Exit Hatches at any time to leave the mission and return to town. Exiting this way, you will keep all of the XP and loot you have earned so far, but you will not get the bonus reward XP  for completing the mission.

When you are in a Story Mission, you can *not* exit the mission. This is quite unfortunate. Once you start it, the only outcomes are to return to an earlier save; to complete the mission; or to die. If your entire party dies, you will have to start over from a previous save anyway. For this reason, you may want to complete several regular missions before taking on a Story Mission, to level up your party. You may also want to bring along healing supplies such as Medkits.

From the [Starcrawler Release Notes, May 2017:](https://store.steampowered.com/newshub/app/318970/old_view/236843916082626731) "Abort Mission has been removed. To successfully exit a mission, you’ll have to make it to one of several conveniently lit exit doors. No free escapes".

Comment: Where is the option to save/load?? I can't find anything other than the autosaves. I have to restart the game because of this